# Fail to average IndexedSlices on porting ptb_word_lm.py to multi-GPU-towers

Tags: tensorflow

I try to port RNN model in [ptb_word_lm.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) to multi-GPU cards. I follow the multi-tower style in [cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py). However, I found the "grads" returned by `tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cost, tvars), config.max_grad_norm)` is not list of Tensor type. It is a list of type `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.IndexedSlices`.
Now I need to sum & average the lists of "grads" returned by multiple GPU towers into one list of IndexedSlices or Tensor, in order to pass it into 
`self._train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars))`. 
I've tried the `tf.convert_to_tensor` to conver IndexedSlices to Tensor, but it failed with the following errors:

```
File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 150, in __init__
    grads_0_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(grads[0])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", 
    line 566, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py",
    line 77, in _IndexedSlicesToTensor
    % str(value))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested for IndexedSlices without dense_shape:
IndexedSlices(indices=Tensor("model/gradients/concat_1:0", shape=(400,), dtype=int32),
values=Tensor("model/clip_by_global_norm/model/clip_by_global_norm/_0:0",
shape=(?, 200), dtype=float32))
```

How could I merge these IndexedSlices? Or is there any example code that parallelize RNN in multi-GPU-towers style?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I knew how to average several IndexedSlices. Two choices:

1. from `tensorflow.python.ops import gradients`, then use the function `gradients._IndexedSlicesToTensor` convert them to tensors.
2. concatenate along the first dimension to get the sum, the use the `IndexedSlices.values / n` to get the average.

Answer (score 0):

Indexed slices support repeated indices. So to combine them as a sum, it suffices to concatenate then (both indices and values) along the first axis.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow `HY G`'s second way, I got the following code:

```
values = tf.concat([x.values for x in grads_per_model],0)
indices = tf.concat([x.indices for x in grads_per_model],0)
agg_grad = tf.IndexedSlices(values, indices)
```